# .NET Routing contain case sensitive?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, url-routing

I was working with routes in .NET Core and I noticed that when I use the same route but passing it with a lowercase letter, I got access to the same page.

Example:
mydomain.com/Account/Login
mydomain.com/account/login

Why was there no distinction between uppercase and lowercase in this case? And I am not using `services.AddRouting (options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);` to allow this.

I just want to know how that letter distinction works and why it continues to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quote from the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-template-reference) :

> Text matching is case-insensitive and based on the decoded representation of the URL's path.

And `services.AddRouting (options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);` is just used to convert the route template to lowercase. But you can still access it with uppercase Url.

Comment: If matching is case-insensitive, what's the point of lowercasing the route templates? Why there's such option?

Comment: I guess I figured it out... it can be useful when generating automatic links with anchor tag helpers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0